# Why is a HTML form field showing the calculations in the output field

Tags: javascript, calculator

I've created a basic profit calculator which is pretty much working fine. My issue is that every time I enter a number into each of the relevant fields, you can see the workings out in the "Total profit" field. It first tells me my entry is NaN, then -infinity, and then shows the workings. Once I click on my calculate button, I am then finally displayed with the correct number.

For this post I am not concerned with why it is producing the NaN (not a number), but why am I seeing it populated in the field in the first place. I want this field to remain blank until I click Calculate, and then see the resulting number. I suspect it's to do with my JavaScript code but I am a complete newbie - and very stuck.

Your thoughts are most appreciative.

```
<form id="profitCalculator" action="" class="dark-matter">
<h1>Profit Calculator</h1>

<fieldset>
<p><label>Case Cost:<br />£
<input name="casecost" type="text" value="" size="14" maxlength="8" /></label></p>

<p><label>Units per case:<br />&nbsp; <input name="packs" type="text" value="1" size="14" maxlength="8" /></label></p>

<p><label>Sell price:<br /> £ <input name="sell_price" type="text" value="" size="14" maxlength="8" /></label></p>

<p><input type="button" class="button" OnClick="Circle_calc(this.form);" value="Calculate"></p>

<p>Total Profit:<br /> £ <input name="profit" type="text" value="0" autocomplete="off" SIZE=14></p>

<p><input type="reset" class="button" value="Reset"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And the JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('profitCalculator').onclick = function () {
var casecost = this.elements['casecost'].value || 0;
var packs = this.elements['packs'].value || 0;
var sell_price = this.elements['sell_price'].value || 0;
var profit = (sell_price - casecost) / packs;
this.elements['profit'].value = profit.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You've set a `click` handler on the `form` element. Since `click` events *bubble*, clicks on the elements *inside* the form bubble to the form as well. So that's triggering an update to your profit element on anything that any element considers a click.

This diagram from the [DOM3 events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) (which has since been folded into the [DOM4 spec's events section](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#events)) may help clarify how bubbling works:

[image: DOM diagram showing event capture flowing from the document to the target element, and event bubbling flowing back from the element up to the document]

Answer (score -1):

You have a Onclick event on your button that calls Circle_calc function.

Change your function passing the form element as a parameter, and it will work.

```
Circle_calc = function (form) {
var casecost = form.elements['casecost'].value || 0;
var packs = form.elements['packs'].value || 0;
var sell_price = form.elements['sell_price'].value || 0;
var profit = (sell_price - casecost) / packs;
form.elements['profit'].value = profit.toFixed(2);
}
```

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7khxs3a/)